# How can I use flexboxes to keep my elements moving together?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a liquid layout and I'm coming across a problem where my elements move out of place relative to each other. I just want my layout to move according to my numbers.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column wrap;
}

#firstNum {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 320%;
  left: 43%;
  top: 15%;
}

@media all and (min-height: 50%) {
  #firstNum {
    order: 1;
  }
  #sign {
    order: 2;
  }
  #line {
    order: 3;
  }
}

#sign {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 320%;
  left: 40%;
  top: 24%;
}

#line {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 320%;
  top: 28%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="firstNum" class="flex-item"> &nbsp 10 <br> &nbsp 35</div>
  <div id="sign" class="flex-item">+</div>
  <div id="line" class="flex-item">_____</div>
</div>
```

what I want:

[image]

what it does:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. I would like to just use flexboxes for this.

Comment: so you're specyfing flex container and use absolute positioned elements in it. that does not make much sense

Comment: It's the only way I can figure to make the formatting like I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use flex, then keep element in the flow. Flex has some specifity you can use to style the content without need to create html tags for the visual.

example

```css
/* flex */

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

b:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;
}


/* styling aside flex */

div {
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 2.35em; /* will make content to wrap into next-col */
  width: 2.5em;
  border-bottom: solid;
}

div b {
  background: yellow;
  text-align: right;
  width: 1em;
  padding: 0 0.25em 0 0.5em;
}

div b:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  margin: 0.75em -0.5em 1em 0;
  width: 0.55em;
  padding: 0;
}


/* fun */

div {
  position: relative;
  margin:0.5em auto 2em;
}

div:after, p:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  content: '=45';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px, 1px 1px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: script;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align:left;
}

div:hover:after,
p:hover:after{
  opacity: 1;
}
p:after {
position:static;
}
```

```html
When flex is understood:
<div>
  <b>10</b>
  <b>+</b>
  <b>35</b>
</div>
when it is not , content still makes sens:
<p>
  <b>10</b>
  <b>+</b>
  <b>35</b>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution purely with flexbox. You may need to adjust the margin to achieve the desired spacings.

I also changed the line to be simply a top border, which is way better than styling a text to achieve a horizontal line.

```css
.flex-container
{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}

#firstNum {    background-color:yellow;
    font-size: 320%;
    order: 1;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
@media all and (min-height: 50%){
    #firstNum {order:2;}
    #sign {order:1;}
    #line {order:3;}

}


#sign
{   

    background-color:red;
    font-size: 320%;
    order: 0;
    height: 70px;
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#line
{   
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    order: 2;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class ="flex-container">
<div id = "firstNum" class ="flex-item"> &nbsp 10 </br> &nbsp 35</div>
<div id = "sign" class="flex-item">+</div>
<div id ="line" class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So if I were wanting to put this equation in the center would I just align:center?

Comment: no, you need to add `margin: 0 auto` to flex-container.

Comment: I edited my answer to center the equation. Take a look also at https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column wrap;
  font-size: 320%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 43%;
  top: 15%;
}

#firstNum {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-right: .5em;
  margin-left: -.3em;
  padding-right: .3em;
  order: 2;
}

#sign {
  background-color: red;
  order: 1;
  margin-left: .2em;
  margin-top: .6em;
  margin-bottom: .6em;
  z-index: 10;
}

@media all and (min-height: 50%) {
  #firstNum {
    order: 1;
  }
  #sign {
    order: 2;
  }
  #line {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="firstNum" class="flex-item"> &nbsp 10 <br> &nbsp 35</div>
  <div id="sign" class="flex-item">+</div>
</div>
```